# k-means clustering in R on very large, sparse matrix?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, sparse-matrix

I am trying to do some k-means clustering on a very large matrix.

The matrix is approximately 500000 rows x 4000 cols yet very sparse (only a couple of "1" values per row).

The whole thing does not fit into memory, so I converted it into a sparse ARFF file. But R obviously can't read the sparse ARFF file format. I also have the data as a plain CSV file.

Is there any package available in R for loading such sparse matrices efficiently? I'd then use the regular k-means algorithm from the cluster package to proceed.

Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I got another question though :-) I am trying to run bigkmeans with a cluster number of about 2000 e.g "clust <- bigkmeans(mymatrix, centers=2000)"

However, I get the following error: 
Error in 1:(10 + 2^k) : result would be too long a vector

Can someone maybe give me a hint what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Original at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177827/clustering-on-very-large-sparse-matrix

Answer (score 14):

The [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/package=bigmemory) package (or now family of packages -- see their [website](http://www.bigmemory.org)) used k-means as running example of extended analytics on large data. See in particular the sub-package [biganalytics](http://cran.r-project.org/package=biganalytics) which contains the k-means function.

Comment: +1 for big memory, i had no idea that they had so many packages.

Comment: Yes and the read.data.matrix() function from bigmemory package supports 1 atomic data type.

Answer (score 1):

Please check:

```
library(foreign)
?read.arff
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

sparkcl performs sparse hierarchical clustering and sparse k-means clustering
This should be good for R-suitable (so - fitting into memory) matrices.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparcl/sparcl.pdf

==

For really big matrices, I would try a solution with Apache Spark sparse matrices, and MLlib - still, do not know how experimental it is now:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrices$

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a special SparseM package for R that can hold it efficiently. If that doesn't work, I would try going to a higher performance language, like C.