# clustering on very large sparse matrix?

Tags: matrix, cluster-analysis, data-mining, sparse-matrix, k-means

I am trying to do some (k-means) clustering on a very large matrix.

The matrix is approximately 500000 rows x 4000 cols yet very sparse (only a couple of "1" values per row). I want to get around 2000 clusters.

I got two questions:
- Can someone recommend an open source platform or tool for doing that (maybe using k-means, maybe with something better)?
- How can I best estimate the time the algorithm will need to finish? I tried weka once, but aborted the job after a couple of days because I couldn't tell how much time it would take.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for a real time application or for your own self development?

Comment: Reasked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039646/k-means-clustering-in-r-on-very-large-sparse-matrix .

Answer (score 1):

http://lucene.apache.org/mahout/

Comment: Please don't post just links as answers, explain why this answers the question of the OP

Answer (score 1):

For your case, I guess your problem is only in the size of the input.

I would suggest "cluto" as a good tool for large and sparse dataset.
It is written in C. I have tried around 17 millions of rows with around 400 cols.
And it works fast.

[Link of the Cluto library](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/cluto/cluto/overview)

Answer (score 0):

You can try sparcl package in R, it implements sparse k-means and hierarchical clustering. Not so easy to understand tough

Comment: be careful, sparcl is 'sparse' in feature selection and does not address the n^2 storage for the similarity matrix.