# R, issue with a Hierarchical clustering after a Multiple correspondence analysis

Tags: r, bigdata, cluster-computing

I want to cluster a dataset (600000 observations), and for each cluster I want to get the principal components.
My vectors are composed by one email and by 30 qualitative variables.
Each quantitative variable has 4 classes: 0,1,2 and 3.

So first thing I'm doing is to load the library FactoMineR and to load my data:

```
library(FactoMineR)
mydata = read.csv("/home/tom/Desktop/ACM/acm.csv")
```

Then I'm setting my variables as qualitative (I'm excluding the variable 'email' though):

```
for(n in 1:length(mydata)){mydata[[n]] <- factor(mydata[[n]])}
```

I'm removing the emails from my vectors:

```
mydata2 = mydata[2:31]
```

And I'm running a MCA in this new dataset:

```
mca.res <- MCA(mydata2)
```

I now want to cluster my dataset using the hcpc function:

```
res.hcpc <- HCPC(mca.res)
```

But I got the following error message:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1296.0 Gb
```

What do you think I should do? Is my dataset too large? Am I using well the hcpc function?

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue with a dummy dataset. I think you are using HCPC the correct way, as well as MCA. I think you may want to look into sparse clustering algorithms since HCPC is agnes based. CLARA may be useful but others are available.

Answer (score 5):

Since it uses hierarchical clustering, `HCPC` needs to compute the lower triangle of a 600000 x 600000 distance matrix (~ 180 billion elements). You simply don't have the RAM to store this object and even if you did, the computation would likely take hours if not days to complete.

There have been various discussions on Stack Overflow/Cross Validated on clustering large datasets; some with solutions in R include:

[k-means clustering in R on very large, sparse matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039646/k-means-clustering-in-r-on-very-large-sparse-matrix) (`bigkmeans`)

[Cluster Big Data in R and Is Sampling Relevant?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55177/cluster-big-data-in-r-and-is-sampling-relevant) (`clara`)

If you want to use one of these alternative clustering approaches, you would apply it to `mca.res$ind$coord` in your example.

Another idea, suggested in response to the problem [clustering very large dataset in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984940/clustering-very-large-dataset-in-r), is to first use k means to find a certain number of cluster centres and then use hierarchical clustering to build the tree from there. This method is actually implemented via the `kk` argument of `HCPC`.

For example, using the `tea` data set from `FactoMineR`:

```
library(FactoMineR)
data(tea)
## run MCA as in ?MCA
res.mca <- MCA(tea, quanti.sup = 19, quali.sup = c(20:36), graph = FALSE)
## run HCPC for all 300 individuals
hc <- HCPC(res.mca, kk = Inf, consol = FALSE)
## run HCPC from 30 k means centres
res.consol <- NULL ## bug work-around
hc2 <- HCPC(res.mca, kk = 30, consol = FALSE)
```

The `consol` argument offers the option to consolidate the clusters from the hierarchical clustering using k-means; this option is not available when `kk` is set to a real number, hence `consol` is set to `FALSE` here. The object `res.consul` is set to `NULL` to work around a minor bug in `FactoMineR` 1.27.

The following plot show the clusters based on the 300 individuals (`kk = Inf`) and based on the 30 k means centres (`kk = 30`) for the data plotted on the first two MCA axes:

[image]

It can be seen that the results are very similar. You should easily be able to apply this to  your data with 600 or 1000 k means centres, perhaps up to 6000 with 8GB RAM. If you wanted to use a larger number, you'd probably want to code a more efficient version using `bigkmeans`, `SpatialTools::dist1` and `fastcluster::hclust`.

Answer (score 0):

That error message usually indicates that R has not enough RAM at its disposal to complete the command. I guess you are running this within 32bit R, possibly under Windows? If this is the case, then killing other processes and deleting unused R variables might possibly help: for example, you might try to delete `mydata`, `mydata2` with

```
rm(mydata, mydata2)
```

(as well as all other non-necessary R variables) before executing the command which generates the error. However the ultimate solution in general is to switch to 64bit R, preferably under 64bit Linux and with a decent RAM amount, also see here:

[R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)

[R Memory Allocation "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 75.1 Mb"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917532/r-memory-allocation-error-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-75-1-mb?rq=1)

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-td3629384.html

Comment: I replicated that issue on a 64bit R for Linux machine with 32GB ram and 12 cores, it is just a big data issue rather than a 32bit issue.

Comment: 1296.0 Gb seems big indeed.

Comment: @FMKerckhof I'm using ubuntu on a 64bit R. So your point is there is nothing I can do?

Comment: Not if you stick to your initial code, there's just very few computers with the necessary amount of RAM and even if there were it would take quite some time to run. But the answer above by Heather Turner is an excellent solution (as I already suggested in my original comment to your question: using clara or other sparse clustering methods are probably your only solution here).